# Preprocess shortest paths under contention

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, shortest-path, proof

It is easy to prove that if P is a shortest path between u and v, then every subpath is also a shortest path. 
Given a connected Graph, I want to preprocess a the shortest path between every pair of nodes in a Matrix, such that:

1. Path[u,v] = Path[v,u]
2. If x,y in Path[u,v] then Path[x,y] is a subpath of Path[u,v].

I can not figure out an algorithm or a prove and actually I do not know if this is posible. 
Any idea is welcome.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get (1) if you are working with undirected graphs OR if it is guaranteed that the weight of the arc (a, b) is equal to the weight of the arc (b, a) for all arcs in your graph.

The problem you describe sounds like the all-pairs shortest path problem: for each pair of nodes in a connected graph, find the shortest paths between nodes in the pair. The Floyd-Warshall algorithm can be used to find the lengths of paths and it is straightforward to reconstruct the shortest paths from there.

This algorithm further requires that there are no negative cycles (otherwise a shorter path could always be obtained by running through that cycle again) but that requirement seems reasonable.

To guarantee property (2), you need to make sure when reconstructing paths you are reconstructing "canonical" paths whenever more than one shortest path may be possible. To do this, impose an ordering on the vertices and always test candidate nodes in ascending order, always preferring the lowest-ordered node which maintains the shortest-path property.

Wikipedia has a fairly good write-up.